# How to document a function or variable output by a custom hook

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Say I have a hook. I want the jsdoc descriptions to appear when you hover over the variables in App. Currently only the typescript type annotations appear, like
`const printBar: PrintBar` shows on hover. But I want it to show `Prints bar.`

```js
// useFooBar.tsx

/**
 * A foo bar.
 */
export type FooBar = {
  foo: string;
  bar: string;
};

/**
 * Prints bar.
 */
export type PrintBar = () => void;

export type FooBarUtils = [
  FooBar,
  Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<FooBar>>,
  PrintBar,
];

export function useFooBar(): FooBarUtils {
  const [fooBar, setFooBar] = useState<FooBar>({ foo: 'foo', bar: 'bar' });

  /**
   * Prints bar. This doesn't show either.
   */
  const printBar: PrintBar = () => console.log(fooBar.bar);

  return [fooBar, setFooBar, printBar];
}
```

```js
// app.tsx

export function App() {
  const [fooBar, setFooBar, printBar] = useFooBar();
  // ...
}
```

Update: Here is my vscode settings

```json
{
  "workbench.colorTheme": "One Monokai",
  "workbench.startupEditor": "newUntitledFile",
  "editor.suggestSelection": "first",
  "vsintellicode.modify.editor.suggestSelection": "automaticallyOverrodeDefaultValue",
  "files.exclude": {
    "**/.classpath": true,
    "**/.project": true,
    "**/.settings": true,
    "**/.factorypath": true
  },
  "java.refactor.renameFromFileExplorer": "preview",
  "java.configuration.runtimes": [
    {
      "name": "JavaSE-17",
      "path": "C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk-17",
      "default": true
    }
  ],
  "C_Cpp.default.cppStandard": "c++20",
  "security.workspace.trust.untrustedFiles": "open",
  "code-runner.runInTerminal": true,
  "terminal.integrated.scrollback": 10000,
  "settingsSync.ignoredSettings": ["-emmet.extensionsPath"],
  "java.inlayHints.parameterNames.enabled": "none",
  "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "Git Bash",
  "javascript.updateImportsOnFileMove.enabled": "always",
  "[typescriptreact]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
  },
  "typescript.updateImportsOnFileMove.enabled": "always",
  "[python]": {
    "editor.formatOnType": true
  },
  "[json]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
  },
  "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "editor.tabSize": 2,
  "diffEditor.ignoreTrimWhitespace": false,
  "debug.javascript.autoAttachFilter": "onlyWithFlag",
  "scm.alwaysShowRepositories": true
}
```

Comment: Will have to share your settings.json (if vscode) to see the full picture. FYI it works for me